# How variable_get and variable_set works in drupal

Tags: 6, configuration

How do variables work? Is it as simple as using

```
variable_set('myvar', 'my_value');
```

to set, and

```
variable_get('myvar');
```

to retrieve?

Additionally, where are these variables stored, and do they have any sort of categorisation/access control (i.e. can any module get the variables set by any other module)?

**Update from comment**

I can see a line like `$custom_theme = variable_get('admin_theme', '0');`
But i cant see any `variable_set('admin_theme')` in anywhere in the module though .

Comment: Yes. What's "global storage"?

Comment: means does the variables stores in db or some thing ,also is the variables in a module accessible in that  specific module only ?

Comment: Can you check the edits and make sure that sounds like what you wan tto know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables created through `variable_set()` and `variable_get()` are stored in the variables table in the database.

`variable_set('myvar', 'my_value')` 
is used to change the value of an existing variable to the provided value, or to create a new variable with the provided value if none exists.

`variable_get('myvar', 'optional_default')`
is used to retrieve the value of `myvar`. If `myvar` does not exist, then it is created using the value from `optional_default`. If `optional_default` is not specified, then `myvar` defaults to `Null`.

Comment: how variables tables stores the data even if we do not declare through variable_set() ?

Comment: What if a variable set to true , eg **variable_get('clone_method', TRUE);**

Comment: To prevent `variable_get()` from throwing an error when trying to retrieve a variable that doesn't exist, `variable_get()` creates a variable if one does not exist already.  `variable_get('clone_method', TRUE);` would try to retrieve the `clone_method` variable. If `clone_method` does not exist, it would be created with the value `TRUE`.